# Sonata MediaBundle .tif support

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to configure Sonata MediaBundle to upload various images formats but it's not working for .tif and .tiff image formats. After the upload it throws the following error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Imagine\Exception\RuntimeException: "An image could not be created from the given input" at /var/www/releases/current/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php line 190 {"exception":"[object] (Imagine\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): An image could not be created from the given input at /var/www/releases/current/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php:190)"} []
```

The app is running on Symfony 3.3 with php 7.1 in Linux AWS, other image formats like jpg are working fine

My sonata_media part of config.yml is:

```
sonata_media:
    db_driver: doctrine_orm
    default_context: archivio
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            download:
                strategy: sonata.media.security.public_strategy
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 100}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 100}
        archivio:
            download:
                strategy: sonata.media.security.public_strategy
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 100}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 100}
    cdn:
        server:
            path: 'https://s3-%s3_region%.amazonaws.com/%s3_bucket_name%'

    providers:
        image:
            filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
            allowed_extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'tif', 'tiff']
            resizer: sonata.media.resizer.square
            generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
            allowed_mime_types: ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/tiff']
    filesystem:
        s3:
            sdk_version: 3
            bucket:      '%s3_bucket_name%'
            accessKey:   '%s3_access_key%'
            secretKey:   '%s3_secret_key%'
            region:      '%s3_region%'
            version:     '%s3_version%'
```

Comment: Check that you have Imagick PHP extension installed

Comment: yes, already Installed and enabled